# Datetime X-axis for Boxplot series in TeeChart

Tags: c#, teechart

Currently, I have multiple boxplots in TeeChart that I have added like so:

```
seriesIndex = 0;
foreach(var dataGroup in DataGroups) //Each dataGroup contains all the ParameterValues at a specific point in time
{
    var series = new Box() { ... }
    var values = dataGroup.ParameterValues;
    series.Add(seriesIndex, values);
    seriesIndex++;
    Chart.Series.Add(series);
}
```

I want to convert this so that the X-axis uses a DateTime value (defined as below):

```
var timeIndex = dataGroup.TimeSeriesIndex;
```

However, the Box class's Add method does not support DateTime values. And when I use the inherited (from the base Series class) `Add(DateTime, double)` method (within a foreach loop), all the DateTime values become `12 AM December 31, 1899` which I recognize to be the base value for `DateTime.ToOADate`. This leads me to believe that I am not inputting the data correctly into the series. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all the DateTime values become 12 AM December 31, 1899 which I recognize to be the base value for DateTime.ToOADate.

Exactly, that's the way vertical box plot works in TeeChart. The X position is determined by its [Position property](http://teechart.net/docs/teechart/net/lib/html/SteemaTeeChartStylesCustomBoxPositionProperty.htm), which is zero by default. To achieve what you request you should set a position for each box plot. This can be done assigning the Position property or via the [specific add method override](http://teechart.net/docs/teechart/net/lib/html/SteemaTeeChartStylesCustomBoxAddMethod.htm) as shown in the code snippet below. For DateTime labels, you can just set [XValues.DateTime](http://teechart.net/docs/teechart/net/lib/html/SteemaTeeChartStylesValueListDateTimeProperty.htm) to true and let TeeChart calculate labels automatically or use the labels trick shown in this code:

```
  tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;

  var boxSeries1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Box(tChart1.Chart);
  var boxSeries2 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Box(tChart1.Chart);
  var boxSeries3 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Box(tChart1.Chart);

  boxSeries1.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(0).ToOADate(), new double[6] { 3, 6, 8, 15, 19, 21 });
  boxSeries2.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToOADate(), new double[4] { 5, 7, 12, 21 });
  boxSeries3.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToOADate(), new double[5] { 6, 7, 8, 15, 21 });

  // A simple trick to force custom axis labels on bottom axis.
  // In this case, series titles
  Steema.TeeChart.AxisLabelsItems labels = tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Items;
  labels.Clear();

  foreach (Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Box b in tChart1.Series)
  {
    b.XValues.DateTime = true;
    labels.Add(b.Position);
  }

  tChart1.Axes.Bottom.Labels.DateTimeFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm";
```